# Android: Why would we need to reference a resouce ID from Android Package namespace in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, r.java-file

From the developer guide,

> When referencing an Android resource ID, you do not need the
>   plus-symbol, but must add the android package namespace, like so:
>
> `android:id="@android:id/empty`

This got me wondering why would we need to refer to a resource ID from the android package namespace *in XML*? So can you give me example(s) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example is the one you quoted from in the documentation, identifying the empty view to use for a `ListActivity`.

Quoting the "Screen Layout" section of [the `ListActivity` JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)
>
> Optionally, your custom view can contain another view object of any type to display when the list view is empty. This "empty list" notifier must have an id "android:id/empty". Note that when an empty view is present, the list view will be hidden when there is no data to display.

Comment: Or in `RelativeLayout` when you specify where one widget goes in relation to another :)

Comment: @LittleChild: Yes, though that would only be true if that other widget had a framework-defined ID.